# Edittext in android using custom array adapter

Tags: android

I am using custom array adapter to show the list of some products. in the list view there are two text views and one Edit text. edit text is getting focused in multiple text field when I click on it to enter the value.

I am not getting actual problem. Trying on it since quite a few day
Please help me out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMRP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/texthint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    </LinearLayout>


package com.example.order;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ModifiedAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Order data[] = null;`enter code here`

    public ModifiedAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Order[] data) {
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // View row = convertView;
        OrderHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new OrderHolder();
            holder.txtBP = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBP);
            holder.txtMRP = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMRP);
            holder.qty = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (OrderHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Order order = data[position];
        holder.txtBP.setText(order.BP);
        holder.txtMRP.setText(order.MRP);

        Log.d("data count : ", ""+getCount());

        return convertView;
    }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}


static class OrderHolder
{
    TextView txtMRP;
    TextView txtBP;
    EditText qty;
}


}
```

The above mentioned is the xml and adapter I am using :) 
And I am not getting any error.

Comment: paste the related code and error or exception that you are facing ... :)

Comment: Paste your **custom array adapter** code

Comment: post your custom adpter code and List row xml

Comment: added the code. Please check :)

Answer (score 0):

replace you XML and check and let me know

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtBP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMRP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/qtyLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"  
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/texthint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: same issue. If I enter the value in one edit text same value will be entered into next 5th edit or something. And once u touch and drag the screen values will be replaced in some other edit text